# После последнего else всё равно выводит целое число, хотя надо дробное. Что делать?

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
   int  k;
   double k1;
    
    cout << "введите положительное количество грибов:  ";
    cin >> k;
    k1 = k;
    

    cout << "мы нашли ";

    if (floor(k) == k)
    
    {
      if ((k % 100 == 11) || (k % 100 == 12) || (k % 100 == 13) || (k % 100 == 14))
    
      {
        cout << k << " грибов в лесу" << endl;

        return 0;

      }
    
      if (k % 10 == 1)
    
      {
        cout << k << " гриб в лесу" << endl;

        return 0;
    
      }
    
      if ((k % 10 == 2) || (k % 10 == 3) || (k % 10 == 4))
    
      {
        cout << k << " гриба в лесу" << endl;

        return 0;
    
      }
    
      if ((k % 10 > 4) || (k % 10 == 0))
    
      {
        cout << k << " грибов в лесу" << endl;

        return 0;
    
      }

    }
   
    else
    {
        cout << k1 << " гриба в лесу";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: А с чего оно должно быть дробным?... Вы же присваиваете `k1` целое значение? И вообще — какой смысл в `floor(k)` для целого числа?!

Comment: вот условие: Для дробного числа К напечатать фразу "мы нашли К грибов в лесу",
согласовав окончание слова "гриб" с числом К. и надо чтобы работало и для целых данных, и для дробных. Как это тогда можно сделать?

Comment: Читать дробное число в переменную типа `double`, а не `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    double  k;
    cout << "введите положительное количество грибов:  ";
    cin >> k;
    cout << "мы нашли ";

    if (floor(k) == k) {
        int m = k;

        if ((m % 100 == 11) || (m % 100 == 12) || (m % 100 == 13) ||
                (m % 100 == 14)) {
            cout << m << " грибов в лесу" << endl;
            }
        else if (m % 10 == 1) {
            cout << m << " гриб в лесу" << endl;
            }
        else if ((m % 10 == 2) || (m % 10 == 3) || (m % 10 == 4)) {
            cout << m << " гриба в лесу" << endl;
            }
        else {
            cout << m << " грибов в лесу" << endl;
            }
        }
    else {
        cout << k << " гриба в лесу";
        }
    }
```